# Will my app get rejected?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, mac-appstore

I'm currently writing a workout logging application in for iOS. My application requires a user to create an account to start logging. All that's required is: username, password, gender, bodyweight. Username/password is used for the initial database row entry, and for unique queries from database. And then gender and bodyweight is used to calculate a Wilks Coefficient (takes into account gender and bodyweight to compare strength among individuals). And that's it. I wrote a privacy policy for this. Was about to submit for review and find out. But looking through the App Review guidelines, it was a tad unclear on the requirements.

Answer (score 3):

As long as it's explicit in the privacy policy, it should be ok. Have you considered adding HealthKit capability?

Comment: Many apps ask for much more than that and they're ok: you're not even asking who they are! There's nothing wrong with it, especially if this information is functional to the scope of your application. If you have a backend, use SSL, store hashes and not passwords, be a good citizen. (note: there's a billion reasons your app could be rejected anyway, certainly not because you're asking gender and weight).